# Sort the smallest n/logn elements in the array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

How to sort the smallest `n/(log n)` elements in the array in `O(n)`?

I know how to sort the smallest `k` elements is `O(n+k*log k)`, but how to use this for my question?

Answer (score 4):

if k=n/(log n), then using the algorithm you know will take O(n+(n/(log n))*log(n/(log n))), and since n > n/(log n), log n > log(n/(log n)), and thus this will also be O(n).

Answer (score 1):

I think your existing solution already does the truck: If you substitute

```
k = n/(log n)
```

you get

```
total = O(n + (n/log n) * log (n / log n))
```

Using `log (a/b) = log a - log b` :

```
total = O(n + (n / log n) * (log n) - (n / log n) *log log n)

total = O(n + n - (n / log n) *log log n)
```

We can throw away the negative term: If `f < g` than something that is `O(f)` will also be  `O(g)`

```
total = O(2 * n)
```

Finally, big-O lets us ignore the constant factor:

```
total = O(n)
```